# "error: expected unqualified-id before '.'" Compiling C++ App with OpenSSL Libraries

Tags: c++, netbeans, openssl, mingw

When attempting to compile code which uses the OpenSSL libraries I receive the following error:

```
In file included from util.h:28:0,
             from addrman.h:9,
             from addrman.cpp:5:
c:/local/openssl-0.9.8za/include/openssl/sha.h:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
../../crypto/sha/sha.h
```

The file listed has the following line of code in it (and this is the only line of code):

```
../../crypto/sha/sha.h
```

Can anyone provide any feedback on this problem? I have referenced the OpenSSL libraries in the Netbeans project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a cygwin-built OpenSSL install that you are trying to use outside of cygwin.

Windows has no symbolic links, cygwin simulates them with regular text files. Windows programs do not consider these files symbolic links.

If you want to keep using your OpenSSL install, replace its "symbolic links" with copies of corresponding regular files.

Comment: Good find n.m. I would have chased that one for a while.